# how can i pass ajax result object from one jquery function to other

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to pass ajax success result object from one jquery function to other.

here is my code :

```
courses += '<a id="grid-item" class="dsd col-sm-6 col-md-4 " style="padding:10px; cursor:pointer" onclick="func("+result[i].subcourses+")" >';
```

my jquery function is :

```
function func(data)
  {
  }
```

but is giving me error. result[i].subcourses is object type

how can I achive this .. any help appreciated. thanks in advance

full code :

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadCourse", "CourseMenu")',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                idsubCoursecategory: Number(subcategoryid)
            },
            success: function (result) {


                if (result != null) {
                    if (result.length != 0) {
                        courses += '<h5 class="subcat-text">' + varsubcategoryname + '</h5>';
                        courses += "<div class='row' id='grid'>";

                        for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
                            var myid;

                            if (result[i].hassubcourse == false) {

                                courses += '<div id="grid-item" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" style="padding:10px; cursor:pointer" onclick="fnLoadCourseMaster(\'' + result[i].coursecode + '\', ' + divid + ', \'' + varcoursetypename + '\', ' + varcoursecategoryid + ', \'' + varcoursecategoryname + '\', ' + subcategoryid + ', \'' + varsubcategoryname + '\', \'' + result[i].coursename + '\')">';
                                courses += "<div class='thumbnail'>";
                                courses += "<img src='../../Images/dotnet4logo.jpg' alt='coursing' width='100px' height='100px'>";
                                // courses += "<hr /'>";
                                courses += "<div class='caption'>";
                                courses += "<h3 >" + result[i].coursename + "</h3>";
                                courses += '</div>';
                                courses += '</div>';
                                courses += '</div>';




                            }
                            else {

                                courses += '<a id="grid-item" class="dsd col-sm-6 col-md-4 " style="padding:10px; cursor:pointer" onclick="func()" >';
                                courses += "<div class='thumbnail'>";
                                courses += "<img src='../../Images/dotnet4logo.jpg' alt='coursing' width='100px' height='100px'>";
                                // courses += "<hr /'>";
                                courses += "<div class='caption'>";
                                courses += "<h3 >" + result[i].coursename + "</h3>";
                                courses += "<input type='hidden' value='" + result[i].subcourses + "'>";
                                courses += '</div>';
                                courses += '</div>';
                                courses += '</a>';



                            }


                        }
                        courses += '</div>';

                        $("#divCoursesEngine-" + divid).append(courses);
                    }
                    else {

                        noresultmsg += '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
                        noresultmsg += '<strong>Oops.!</strong> no result found for selected criteria.';
                        noresultmsg += '</div>';
                        $("#divCoursesEngine-" + divid).append(noresultmsg);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert("hi");
                }






            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('An error occurred while Data fetching.'); },
            complete: function () { }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Without seeing some code there is not much we can do, why don't you rather build an Object that your method expects and then pass it. Use success function data to construct your object and and then pass it to the other method.

Comment: I posted full code. can u please refer. in else condition i want to call func() by passing result[i].subcourses object

Answer (score 0):

You can write as value='" + JSON.stringify(result[i].subcourses) + "' ............
and if you want back in JSON you can convert that string as JSON.parse(value).

Let me know if you want more help